# Prevent TWIG from removing a space before a variable

Tags: twig

I have this use case.

Default text, in a span, to be used throughout page. 
Use jQuery to change text from "placeholder" to "specific case"

Ie,

Inside html i want to do this:
(twig / html & js)

```
{% block content %}
{% set location = '<span id="location">Somewhere</span>' %}

<p>Hey, hows the weather in {{ location | raw }}?</p>


<script>
    var location = detectLocation();
    update $(#location).html('location');
<script>
```

Desired output pre script running:

> Hey, hows the weather in Somewhere?

Desired output post script running (assumes it outputs Austrailia):

> Hey, hows the weather in Australia?

..But what I get thanks to twig stripping spaces:

> Hey, hows the weather inSomewhere?

Comment: twqig does not strip spaces by [default](https://twigfiddle.com/zqta32)

Comment: But in html "How is <span>things</span>? will preserve the space

Comment: Are you using twig alone or twig-symfony and what version?

Comment: Twig does not automatically strip spaces

Comment: I am using twig 1.*

Comment: @Nick did you find the solution to this issue? We have the same but in a drupal 8 setup.

Comment: I got the same problem after migrating from window to macOS. do you get a solution?

Comment: @kevinius do you find a solution?

Comment: @kevinius seeing the same problem here using twig 1.* after migrating from php7.0 to php7.4 ... so weird.

Answer (score 19):

This happened to me after moving from php7.0 to php7.4.3 on a legacy codebase that was still using twig 1.*.

If you can't update twig to a newer version, here's the fix.

edit `twig/twig/lib/Twig/Lexer.php`, on line 163 change:

```
if (isset($this->positions[2][$this->position][0]) ) {
    $text = rtrim($text);
}
```

to

```
if (isset($this->positions[2][$this->position][0]) && ($this->options['whitespace_trim'] === $this->positions[2][$this->position][0])) {
   $text = rtrim($text);
}
```

Even better fix: update your version of twig.

Comment: After moving my server to a new one it took me weeks to find this answer and realize it was a conflict of the old Twig 1.16.3 with PHP 7. We moved Twig into Composer, updated Twig version and now this problem is gone.

Comment: I got this exact same bug with Twig 2.4.3 when updating to Debian 11, fix is also same except line to fix is 149