# Preserve whitespace between variables in twig (1.*) template

Tags: php, twig, wpml

Forced to piggyback on WPML's twig setup in a wordpress plugin. So stuck with their setup and twig 1.32.0.

Is there some way I can force twig to keep whitespace between variables?

```
{% set foo = "foo" %}
{% set bar = "bar" %}
<p>{{ foo }} {{ bar }}</p>
```

Expected output:

foo bar

Acctual output:

foobar

I really don't want to use &nbsp . I can't change how WPML has setup twig so i need something I can use in my template directly to fix this.

Comment: seems to work just fine here: https://twigfiddle.com/rgdrk1 is `&nbsp;` an option: `<p>{{ foo }}&nbsp;{{ bar }}</p>` or what you can also try is: `{{ foo ~ ' ' ~ bar }}`

Comment: Yes, I expect it to work in a clean environment , but I think WPML has set twig to stip all whitespace. So I need to unset it for my templates.

Comment: > you can also try is: {{ foo ~ ' ' ~ bar }}

That is something I can work with that is much more readable than &nbsp! Thanks

Comment: You can fix this by adjusting the [lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123721/prevent-twig-from-removing-a-space-before-a-variable) as you were forced to downgrade your twig version

Comment: Thank you @DarkBee . I could in fact use twig 1.43.1 with out causing conflicts with WPML.

Both your suggestions was most useful